# Mat matrix in OpenCV and 16-byte alignment for SSE

Tags: opencv, sse

I like to test the enhancement of `SSE/SSE2` for processing `OpenCV's Mat`. Since `SSE's` performance enhancement is obvious only for 16-byte alignment data, (1)what do I need to modify the Mat matrix to use with `SSE` registers? What I did was as follow and (2)is that a right way to do it?

```
 void test(Mat flowxy, Mat flowresult)
    {
         __m128 x, y, xsquare, ysquare, ybyx, xRecip , sum, r, theta ;//gen is for general purpose
        float *input = (float*)(flowxy.data);
        for(int i = 0; i  < flowxy.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j + SSE_INCREMENT < flowxy.cols; j = j + SSE_INCREMENT)
                {

                    x = _mm_set_ps(input[flowxy.step * (j+6) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j+4) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j+2) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j) + i ]);
                    y = _mm_set_ps(input[flowxy.step * (j+7) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j+5) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j+3) + i ], input[flowxy.step * (j+1) + i ]);
                    xRecip  = _mm_rcp_ps(x);
                    xsquare = _mm_mul_ps(x, x);
                    ysquare = _mm_mul_ps(y, y);             
                    ybyx = _mm_mul_ps(xRecip , y);
                    sum = _mm_add_ps(xsquare, ysquare);
                    r = _mm_sqrt_ps(sum);
                    theta = taninverse(ybyx);
                }


            }

    }
```

I reverse the order in setting `_mm_set_ps` according to the discussion [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/optimization/getting-started-with-sse-programming/).

EDIT 1:

```
void CObjectDetection_TrackingDlg::flow_XY_RTHETA(Mat flowxy, vector<Mat> &flowrtheta)
{
    clock_t start;   
    clock_t finish;  
    start = clock();
    flowrtheta.resize(2);
    if(flowrtheta[0].empty() && flowrtheta[1].empty()){
        flowrtheta[0].create(cvSize(flowxy.rows, flowxy.cols), CV_32FC1);
        flowrtheta[1].create(cvSize(flowxy.rows, flowxy.cols), CV_32FC1);
    }
    vector<Mat> flowxy_S;
    split(flowxy, flowxy_S);
    printMatGrayDatainfloat(flowxy_S[0]);
    printMatGrayDatainfloat(flowxy_S[1]);
    //check SSE2 available
    bool useSIMD = checkHardwareSupport(CV_CPU_SSE);
    if( useSIMD )
    {
        __m128 x, y, xsquare, ysquare, ybyx, xRecip , sum, r, theta ;//gen is for general purpose       
        __declspec(align(16)) struct { int i, j; } sub;
        for(sub.i = 0; sub.i  < flowxy.rows; sub.i++)
        {
            const float *input_x = flowxy_S[0].ptr<float>(sub.i);
            const float *input_y = flowxy_S[1].ptr<float>(sub.i);
            float *output_r = flowrtheta[0].ptr<float>(sub.i);
            float *output_t = flowrtheta[1].ptr<float>(sub.i);
            for(sub.j = 0; sub.j + 4 < flowxy.cols; sub.j = sub.j + 4)
            {

                x = _mm_loadu_ps(&input_x[sub.j]);
                y = _mm_loadu_ps(&input_y[sub.j]);
                xRecip  = _mm_rcp_ps(x);
                xsquare = _mm_mul_ps(x, x);
                ysquare = _mm_mul_ps(y, y);             
                ybyx = _mm_mul_ps(xRecip , y);
                sum = _mm_add_ps(xsquare, ysquare);
                r = _mm_sqrt_ps(sum);
                theta = taninverse(ybyx);
                _mm_storeu_ps(&output_r[sub.j], r);
                _mm_storeu_ps(&output_t[sub.j], theta);

            }


        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i  < flowxy.rows; i++)
        {
            const float *input_x = flowxy_S[0].ptr<float>(i);
            const float *input_y = flowxy_S[1].ptr<float>(i);
            float *output_r = flowrtheta[0].ptr<float>(i);
            float *output_t = flowrtheta[1].ptr<float>(i);
            for(int j = 0; j  < flowxy.cols; j++)
            {
                double x_sq = input_x[j] * input_x[j];
                double y_sq = input_y[j] * input_y[j];
                double y_by_x =  input_y[j] / input_x[j];
                output_r[j] = sqrt(x_sq + y_sq);
                output_t[j] = atan(y_by_x);
            }


        }


    }
    flowxy_S[0].release();
    flowxy_S[1].release();
    finish = clock() - start;
    double interval = finish / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //printMatGrayDatainfloat(flowrtheta[0]);
    //printMatGrayDatainfloat(flowrtheta[1]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your code is more or less OK, since you are not doing any loads or stores which would require 16 byte alignment. However using `_mm_set_ps` is very inefficient - you should use `_mm_loadu_ps` to load contiguous misaligned data and then shuffle the elements into the required order using e.g. `_mm_shuffle_ps`.

Comment: Let me explore more and will catch with you. My r and theta are the result I need to write back to 2-channel Mat flowresult. What could be the best way? Thanks

Comment: You can use `_mm_storeu_ps` to write the results back to memory.

Comment: @PaulR I have updated. I compared two processes in if{} and else{}. The process in the else{} 0.411msec and in the if{} is 0.419msec. Why the process in the if{} is not four time faster? Is it because of unaligned memory?

Comment: It's possible that the compiler is vectorising this code anyway, so you may not gain anything from explicit vectorisation - look at the generated code for your scalar branch and see if it contains SSE instructions. Also note that misaligned loads/stores on old CPUs are quite expensive (you should be OK if this is e.g. a Core i7 though).

Comment: @PaulR Yeah I look at the assembly and I see MULSS, DIVSS commands.

Comment: @PaulR I like to close this. Could you pls answer?

Comment: Sure - I've now re-posted that last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the compiler is vectorising this code anyway, so you may not gain anything from explicit vectorisation - look at the generated code for your scalar branch and see if it contains SSE instructions. Also note that misaligned loads/stores on old CPUs are quite expensive (you should be OK if this is e.g. a Core i7 though).